# c++ adding random(i think) numbers in the end of string output

Tags: c++, string, output

I started using HackerRank and my code is outputting the correct outputs, but it is adding random numbers at the end of the string outputs. I have solved a couple more problems on CodeBlocks and tried it there. It is the same as the one on HackerRank.

[image: expected and my output]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int input1;
    int input2;
    cin>>input1;
    cin>>input2;
    int aralik=input2-input1;
    for(int i=0;i<(aralik+1);i++){
        if((input1+i)<10){
            if((input1+i)==9){
                cout<<printf("nine")<<endl;
            }else if((input1+i)==8){
                cout<<printf("eight")<<endl;
            }else if((input1+i)==7){
                cout<<printf("seven")<<endl;
            }else if((input1+i)==6){
                cout<<printf("six")<<endl;
            }else if((input1+i)==5){
                cout<<printf("five")<<endl;
            }else if((input1+i)==4){
                cout<<printf("four")<<endl;
            }else if((input1+i)==3){
                cout<<printf("three")<<endl;
            }else if((input1+i)==2){
                cout<<printf("two")<<endl;
            }else if((input1+i)==1){
                cout<<printf("one")<<endl;
            }
        }else if((input1+i)>9){
            if(((input1+i)%2)==0){
                cout<<printf("even")<<endl;
            }else{
                cout<<printf("odd")<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf` prints a string to stdout and returns the number of characters printed, then `cout` prints that number of characters printed to stdout.

Comment: Since this is C++ you really, *really* need to read up on how to use arrays or look-up tables. This kind of code is not sustainable, it's a complete mess to work with. Instead consider writing code from a *data-centric* perspective, as in `const char* numbers[] = { "zero", "one", "two", ... }` and then use that like `cout << numbers[n]`.

Comment: As it looks like you're just getting started with C++ the best place to learn it is not something like Hackerrank, but instead a more formal introduction with proper reference material. Doing challenges is great for testing your knowledge, but you need a foundation to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [`printf` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), the function will return an `int`:

> #### Return value
>
> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings). [...]
>
> If an output error is encountered, a negative value is returned.

So if you do `cout << printf("one") << endl;`, you'll run the `printf`, which will output "one", and then you'll `cout` the return value of the `printf`.

You probably wanted:

```
cout << "one" << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The numbers at the end are not random characters. It is the number of characters **printf** printed.

printf function returns the number of characters it sent to the output.

When 'five' is printed, it has 4 characters, so five4 is printed.
printf is executed first so, five and after cout outputs the number of characters printf returned. So the end result is 'five4'. Either use printf or cout.